# How to connect to a Juniper VPN from Linux

Tags: linux, vpn, juniper

The Windows users have a new client "Juniper Pulse" to connect to the Juniper VPN server.

On Linux, what VPN client do we have to connect to that Juniper VPN, with maximum compatibility?

Please mention the necessary parameters that have to be provided.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

And my favorite method (no java applet required):

Presumably:

- your url: 'https://some.site.com/dana-na/auth/url_default/welcome.cgi' (or whatever)
- your username=username
- your password=password
- you know your realm or you can find it from the web page or with:

-

```
REALM=$(wget -q --no-check-certificate -O - 'https://some.site.com/dana-na/auth/url_default/welcome.cgi' | sed -n 's/.*<input\( [^>]*name="realm" [^>]*\)>.*/\1/p' | sed -n 's/.* value="\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p')
```

After you login, download the following jar (should be done one time only):

https://some.site.com/dana-cached/nc/ncLinuxApp.jar

and unzip it to ~/.juniper_networks/network_connect

Get some new libraries for your 64bit machine
    yum install glibc.i686 zlib.i686 nss-mdns.i686

Go to ~/.juniper_networks/network_connect and

```
sudo chown root:root ncsvc
sudo chmod 6711 ncsvc
chmod 744 ncdiag
chmod +x getx509certificate.sh
```

Get your certificate:

```
./getx509certificate.sh some.site.com company.cert
```

And connect:

```
./ncsvc -h some.site.com -u username -p password -r REALM -f ./company.cert
```

For some sites I noticed that you also need to put the -U switch:

```
./ncsvc -h some.site.com -u username -p password -r REALM -f ./company.cert -U 'https://some.site.com/dana-na/auth/url_default/welcome.cgi'
```

Comment: Any Idea how to enter 2 factor auth information???

Comment: No, sorry. Check if you can make this work: https://code.google.com/p/juniper-vpn/source/browse/trunk/junipervpn.py

Comment: Thanks.  Didn't get the script working but did manage to get the VPN working through the linked page http://makefile.com/.plan/2009/10/juniper-vpn-64-bit-linux-an-unsolved-mystery/.

Comment: One hint to anyone trying to get the above script to work.  I think the Login URL needs to end with /dana-na/auth/url_default/login.cgi.  Got the cookie but the script still is not working for me.

Comment: A small note on getting the realm. In my case, the realm wasn't present as an `input` tag; it was there as a `select` tag. So if the REALM snippet doesn't work for you, try looking in the page source for a `select` element that looks like this: `<select id="realm_17" size="1" name="realm">`. You'll want to grab the `value` attribute of one of the child `option` tags.

Comment: Now openconnect supports Juniper, so this is no longer needed. See http://www.infradead.org/openconnect/juniper.html

Comment: @TimLudwinski, you genius!  I could kiss you right about now.  I was starting to fire up ldconfig and debugging tools only to first try using the trailing 'login.cgi' and for the first time in weeks I got a win over technology!  I'm sure Maven will make me pay later today. ;)

Answer (score 17):

The OpenConnect VPN client has (nascent) support for Juniper SSL VPN.

See the announcement at http://lists.infradead.org/pipermail/openconnect-devel/2015-January/002628.html

**Edit 2015-02-02:**

The Juniper support is coming along nicely now and is definitely ready for more testing. It's reached the point where we're happy to admit to its existence on the OpenConnect web site: http://www.infradead.org/openconnect/juniper.html

Comment: You should include a copy of the announcement in your answer -- that link could go dead at some time in the future leaving your answer null & void. It's OK to leave the link as well as a reference.

Comment: A good point in theory in the general case — but in this case if the server hosting my mailing list archive is offline, so is my git repository. The details in the announcement won't do you much good if you can't get to the code anyway :)

Yes, I could include a *summary* of the announcement, concise and also relatively future-proof so it doesn't include specifics of what has and has not been implemented yet *today*. That summary is best phrased as "OpenConnect has nascent support for Juniper SSL VPN" :)

Comment: Now that openconnect supports Juniper (July 2015) - This is the correct and easier answer. Works for me. I had to manually build openconnect thought.

Answer (score 9):

What I usually do is use `openconnect`, it has to run as root, from the terminal window and you have to use the `--juniper` flag like this:

```
sudo openconnect --juniper http://your.vpn.server.here
```

It will ask for your user name and password and will connect you to your vpn.

The only caveat is that the terminal window has to be open all the time and it may drop once or twice in a day, you have to re-connect.

Comment: It actually doesn't have to run as root - See [Running as non-root user](http://www.infradead.org/openconnect/nonroot.html).

Answer (score 4):

Network-Connect is the Old Juniper VPN. It is no longer used/shipped by juniper, everything is now Pulse secure. The information on this site is old. Pulse Secure is not supported on Linux.

Comment: Thx for the information - the question is indeed 4 years old.

Comment: This is not correct. Pulse Secure actually *is* supported on Linux. The *Pulse Secure* client `pulsesvc` is essentially a drop in replacement for `ncsvc`. The latest version of the *Pulse Secure Desktop Client* was released just this month and now seems to even have a working GUI.

Answer (score 3):

I found this page to be the most use for me. [mad scientist](http://mad-scientist.us/juniper.html)

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 15.10:

- `sudo apt-get install icedtea-7-plugin openjdk-7-jre:i386`
- `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/update-alternatives /usr/sbin/` (this may already exist)
- `sudo apt-get install libstdc++6:i386 lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 libxext6:i386 libxrender1:i386 libxtst6:i386 libxi6:i386`

Then connect to your VPN as you would normally through the web interface. You'll need to allow the IcedTea plugin to run in your browser (I used Firefox) when it prompts you. There are also a number of prompts to trust software from a remote site, and it pop up a terminal for your password.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is answered on Juniper's forum [here](http://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB16188&actp=RSS) - specifically for Network Connect (I'm assuming that's what you're wanting to do). They have excellent screenshots, etc to help you through the process (Five steps).

Comment: The linked page now requires a login.